# Buffered writer in a loop is creating empty lines in txt file

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

Link to entire code: http://pastebin.com/Y0FA7zuG

My code:

```
public void dadUpdateFunction(ArrayList<JTextArea> texts)
{
  try{
    //Specify the file name and path here
    File file =new File("C:\\Users\\Karan\\Documents\\dadTXT.txt");

    /* This logic is to create the file if the
     * file is not already present
     */
    if(!file.exists()){
      file.createNewFile();
    }

    //Here true is to append the content to file
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);

    //BufferedWriter writer give better performance
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    String content = "Karan";
    int i= 0;

    for(i= 0; i<texts.size(); i++)
    {
      content = (texts.get(i).getText() );
      if(i!=0) 
        bw.newLine();

      if(i>0)   
        texts.get(i-1).setEditable(false);
    }

    bw.write(content + "\n");
    //Closing BufferedWriter Stream
    bw.close();

    System.out.println("Data successfully appended at the end of file");

  }catch(IOException ioe){
     System.out.println("Exception occurred:");
  }
}
```

So I have an arraylist of JTextArea. In my program a user can write inth e JTextArea and then click this update button, and the text written in the latest JTextArea box gets added to a txt file. However the output I am getting in my txt file is outputting like this: http://pastebin.com/fijFQKZi

I don't want the empty lines in between the numbers, as this messes up my buffered reader later. Why is it adding these empty lines?

How do I fix this? I am new on here, so if I did not write something properly let me know. T

Thank you!

Comment: Please format your code nicely (i.e. with consistent indentation). As it stands, it looks like you couldn't be bothered to present a nice question, which makes many people less inclined to assist.

Comment: Yes sorry did not know to do that. Done now I think. I am having another problem with my code, can I message you somehow or email you? If you have the time to help of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the last `JTextArea` content and no additional `newLine`, you have to remove

```
if(i!=0) 
    bw.newLine();
```

That add a new line for each `JTextArea`.

Now if this is really what you want you can refactor like this:

```
content = texts.get(texts.size()-1).getText(); // get only the last one
bw.write(content + "\n"); // write last content
for(int i= 0; i<texts.size(); i++)
{
    texts.get(i).setEditable(false);
}
```

Comment: Yes ! I just moved the 
      bw.netLine();
Outside the loop. The only problem now is that I have the first line being blank in the txt file. I think I can fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This confuses me in so many ways. In your loop you constantly give a new value to `content` without doing anything with it until the loop ends. Meanwhile, you write newlines to the buffer except for the first time (that part makes some sense). I think you need to move bw.write(content) inside your loop and remove it after the loop.

```
for(i=0; i<texts.size(); i++)
{
    if(i!=0) {
        bw.newLine();
    }
    bw.write(texts.get(i).getText());
    if(i>0) {    
        texts.get(i-1).setEditable(false);
    }
}
bw.close();
```